# Logic Apps in Azure does not open in Designer window

Tags: azure, function, logic, designer

I am using Free Subscription account in Azure trying to create LogicApps resource although it won't ever open in Designer window. Per below screenshots the error after pressing F12 and Azure status page that says okay in Asia Pacific region. Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUoeO.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiDRm.jpg)

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply; yes I tried more than a month ago and the behvaiour was unchanged. Gave up ever since.